# JS valueOf and toString

Tags: javascript, tostring

What kind of wizardry is going on in `x` that isn't going on in `y`?

```
var x = new Date;
var y = {
    toString: function() {
        return x.toString();
    },
    valueOf: function() {
        return x.valueOf();
    }
};

String(x) // "Mon Mar 23 2015 18:26:40 GMT+0000 (GMT)"
String(y) // "Mon Mar 23 2015 18:26:40 GMT+0000 (GMT)"
'' + x    // "Mon Mar 23 2015 18:26:40 GMT+0000 (GMT)"
'' + y    // "1427135200422"
```

Am I on the right lines thinking that `x` has a primative value that `ToString`s as the date string, but `y` doesn't have the primative value?

Edit:

For what it's worth, would the following work (ES6 here):

```
var y = {
    [Symbol.toPrimitive](...args) {
        return x[Symbol.toPrimitive](...args);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

From section 8.12.8 of the spec:

> When the [[DefaultValue]] internal method of O is called with no hint, then it behaves as if the hint were Number, unless O is a Date object (see 15.9.6), in which case it behaves as if the hint were String.

The `+` operator passes the "PreferredType" hint, which behaves as if there were no hint (though the spec doesn't explain that very well, or if it does I can't find it). Thus, your `x` object "prefers" its string representation, while the `y` object uses the number representation.

Comment: It's made explicit only in "NOTE 1" after the addition operator steps: "No hint is provided in the calls to ToPrimitive in steps 5 and 6."

Comment: Weird. `0 + x` gives a string, `0 - x` gives a number.

Comment: @apsillers ah, OK; I was going by the chart in the `[[ToPrimitive]]` section.

Comment: @user2195592 that's because the `+` operator and the `-` operator have different behaviors. The `+` operator doubles as the string concatenation operator, while the `-` operator is always numeric subtraction.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior of `+` is defined in

> [**11.6.1 The Addition operator ( + )**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1)
>
> The production *AdditiveExpression* : *AdditiveExpression* `+`
>   *MultiplicativeExpression* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let *lref* be the result of evaluating AdditiveExpression.
> 2. Let *lval* be [GetValue](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.1)(*lref*).
> 3. Let *rref* be the result of evaluating MultiplicativeExpression.
> 4. Let *rval* be [GetValue](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.1)(*rref*).
> 5. Let *lprim* be [ToPrimitive](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.1)(*lval*).
> 6. Let *rprim* be [ToPrimitive](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.1)(*rval*).
> 7. If [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8)(*lprim*) is String or [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8)(*rprim*) is String, then
>
>    1. Return the String that is the result of concatenating [ToString](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8)(*lprim*) followed by [ToString](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8)(*rprim*)
> 8. Return the result of applying the addition operation to [ToNumber](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3)(*lprim*) and [ToNumber](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3)(*rprim*). See the Note below [11.6.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.3).
>
> NOTE 1 - No hint is provided in the calls to [ToPrimitive](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.1) in steps 5
>   and 6. All native ECMAScript objects except Date objects handle the
>   absence of a hint as if the hint Number were given; Date objects
>   handle the absence of a hint as if the hint String were given. Host
>   objects may handle the absence of a hint in some other manner.

Therefore, according to the definition of [ToPrimitive](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.1) and [[[DefaultValue]]](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.8),

- ToPrimitive returns `x.toString()` for `x`, because `x` is a Date object, so it's like the hint were String.
- ToPrimitive returns `y.valueOf()` for `y`, because `y` is a non-Date native object, so it's like the hint were Number.

Thus, the addition operator returns different results.

Comment: Wait, why is it `x.toString()`?

Comment: @user2195592 because `x` is a Date instance, and that's what the spec says right there in `NOTE 1`.